# Process.StandardOutput Read method returns empty (sometimes)

Tags: c#, process, wkhtmltopdf, redirectstandardoutput

I am using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to generate a PDF file from a HTML string. The code is pretty much the one that follows:

```
// ...
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

// ...
process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
using (StreamWriter stramWriter = process.StandardInput)
{
    stramWriter.AutoFlush = true;
    stramWriter.Write(htmlCode);
}

byte[] buffer = new byte[32768], file;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    while (true)
    {
        int read = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (read <= 0)
            break;
        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    file = memoryStream.ToArray();
}

process.WaitForExit(60000);
process.Close();

return file;
```

This works as expected, but for one specific piece of HTML, the first call of the `StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read` method returns an empty byte array, in which case the `StandardOutput.EndOfStream` is also true.

I would normally suspect the wkhtmltopdf tool failing to process the HTML input for any reason, but the problem is that this only happens in about two out of five attempts, so I now suspect that this might have something to do with process buffering and output stream reading. However, I don't seem to be able to 
figure out what the exact problem is.

What could cause this behavior?

**Update**

Reading the StandardError was the obvious approach, but did not help, it is always an empty string. Neither did the process.ExitCode (-1073741819) which, based on my knowledge, just states that "the process crashed".

Comment: It you don't read StandardError then you can't find out what went wrong.

Comment: That was my first choice in tackling this issue but it did not help. I updated the question.

Comment: Well, that ExitCode is certainly significant.  -1073741819 == 0xC0000005 == STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.  As nasty as they come.  You need to treat any non-zero ExitCode as a "it did not work" indication.

Comment: @Hans, I am already doing this, but I'd like to know what's causing this error in order to fix it, if anybody has a clue.

Answer (score 0):

After almost a year of production usage, [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) is doing its job, with the issue described above reported not more than five times so far.

The problem usually goes away when adding a DIV somewhere toward the end of the document, with a value of height enough to cause the last line of text to move onto the next page (say 20px), if the page happens to be full.

We knew that the tool sometimes has trouble in properly splitting the HTML content into pages because in such cases it generated (say) seven pages while the page numbering reported only six; so the last page's number was "7 of 6". Maybe it sometimes fails completely and doesn't get to generate the pages at all, we thought. The document is generated from a highly dynamic HTML content. Making a change that resulted in a shorter/longer content without using dummy DIVs was relatively easy, and that's how we got through the errors so far.

Right now we are testing [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).